# Flaw in my proof that $\mathbb Q$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, rational-numbers, fake-proofs

I got an idea about an easy proof that $\mathbb Q$ is countable, one that does not involve the typical ["snake around a grid" argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Countability). However, I fear that I am making the same mistake in using an inequality with infinite cardinalities that I seemed to make in an [early attempt at a short proof of the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4551630/672549). Have I made a mistake, or is this a legitimate proof? If this proof is not correct, can it be remedied with a simple fix (in your own judgment of what a "simple" fix would be)?

> Take it as known, for countable $A$ and $B$, $A\times B$ also is
> countable. Also, take it as known that $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb
>  Z_{>0}$ are countable.
>
> Let $f:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb Q$ be defined
> by $f(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}$. Then, given $q\in \mathbb Q$, there is
> $(a,b)\in Z\times\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $f(a,b)=q$, so $f$ is
> surjective.
>
> Therefore, $cardinality(Z\times\mathbb Z_{>0})\ge cardinality(\mathbb
>  Q)$.
>
> Since $Z\times\mathbb Z_{>0}$ is countable, then $\mathbb Q$ must be
> countable, too. $\square$

(A simple fix might be that it requires proof to say that inequalities with infinite cardinalities work the way we might hope, but that such proof is given in the proof of the CSB theorem, to which an answer to the linked question alludes.)

Comment: don't know why you were downvoted as this is an honest attempt. anyway, to show that $A\times B$ is countable for countable sets $A,B$ the most common way is a "snake around a grid" argument. (of course there are other arguments too; eg consider the injection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a3^b$. but the point is that you still need an argument for that step, and it winds up being the same argument as how one shows $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable in the first place)

Comment: Another thing that probably could use more attention is why this surjection onto $\mathbb Q$ implies there is an injection the other way. (It does, but it’s not completely trivial.)

Comment: also, as an aside, inequalities with infinite cardinalities *do* work the way one hopes, but the point is that you have to prove it first! :-) the problem with your other post isn't that the thing you were using was false, it was that the thing you were using requires a proof, which was precisely what you were trying to prove in the first place

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom That message about CSB is getting conveyed in a variety of comments. Perhaps you could post an answer there to consolidate that message, as that is precisely the mistake I made.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom It is just one downvote (which I cannot understand either)

Comment: Usually, the easiest way to prove countability is to enumerate the set. Here you can do this as follows : For $k=1,2,3,\cdots $ list all fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ with $|a|,|b|\le k$ omitting duplicates. This way , you can list all rational numbers

Comment: This proof is fine, if you assume that the CSB theorem has already been proved, plus the fact that if there is a surjection from $X$ to $Y$, then $\text{card}(X)\geq \text{card}(Y)$. (That fact depends on the axiom of choice.)